# Finding a number that follows a specific number in a sequence

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the below array:

```
int [] array = { 9, 8, 3, 2, 3, 2 };
```

I'd like to write a statement when i pick a number from array, it gives the following number as the result.

for examaple i pick the number 8 and according to the statement it gives to number 3 as result.

Comment: unclear what you're asking!

Comment: @user2946329 I think they mean they want the next number in the list after the one they search for so 8 is at index 1, so they want the one at index 2 which is 3.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Obtain an index of a number in the array, check if next index exists and return a number from your array with the next index.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use `SkipWhile` to reach the location of the search number, skip one, and take the first item after it:

```
var array = new[] { 9, 8, 3, 2, 3, 2 };
var next = array.SkipWhile(n => n != 8).Skip(1).First(); // next==3
```

This code assumes two things:

- The search number `8` is there, and
- The search number is *not* the last number in the sequence.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/iml9kj)

Comment: thanks mate, this is works fine, but i'm looking for a classic way,I mean when first i have to write a for cycle to iterate my array and the a if statement, im just not sure how :)

Comment: @hodekal I'd recommend a `while` loop, not `for`, because you need the index after the loop is over. Use an `if` and a `break` inside to end the loop once you find the index of the desired value. As soon as you are out of the loop, increment the index, see if it's valid, and pick whatever item is at the incremented index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to return the next item in the array after the selection?

If that is the case you can do the following:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, 8);
return array[index + 1];
```

There are some limitations to this implementation, please see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx